# python-kivy show images by data stored in a variable

Tags: python, database, image, kivy

i there is there any way like that shown in the below,

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
root=GridLayout(cols=2)
image="all image data as a string"
image=Image(source=image)
root.add_widget(image)
runTouchApp(root)
```

i tried this but it takes only image path
why i do like this because iam doing an app so that the image data as a string stored in database and i want to display that image without storing it in device storage

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrapping the data in a `BytesIO` object and passing this as `source`, if it doesn't work (can't test right now) you should be able to do so with `core.image.Image` (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.image.html) and then use this image's `texture` attribute to assign to an `kivy.uix.image.Image` instance.

edit: here is an example of loading an image from memory, here using pillow to construct it and get it as a BytesIO object, but you could get that source data from your database all the same

```py
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.uix.image import Image
# NOTE this import is important to ensure kivy is ready to load an image from memory
from kivy.core.window import Window
from PIL import Image as PillowImage, ImageDraw

WIDTH = 1000

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        # create a pillow image
        pillow_image = PillowImage.new(mode='RGBA', size=(WIDTH, WIDTH))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pillow_image)
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, 5):
            draw.line((0, x, x, WIDTH), fill=(x, x, x, 255))
            draw.line((x, WIDTH, WIDTH, WIDTH - x), fill=(x, x, x, 255))

            draw.line((WIDTH, WIDTH - x, WIDTH - x, 0), fill=(x, x, x, 255))
            draw.line((WIDTH - x, 0, 0, x), fill=(x, x, x, 255))

        # create bytes from the image data
        image_bytes = BytesIO()
        pillow_image.save(image_bytes, format='png')
        image_bytes.seek(0)

        # load image data in a kivy texture
        core_image = CoreImage(image_bytes, ext='png')
        texture = core_image.texture
        img = Image(texture=texture)
        return img


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the image data to create a `Texture` and then assign that `Texture` to the `Image`. See the documentation for [Texture](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#module-kivy.graphics.texture) and [Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.Image.texture).